# How do I set up the Unix 'mail' command?

Tags: bash, email, unix, terminal

I've had a look on Google and the man pages for mail, but I can't figure out how to set it up. All I want to do is set up my email address so that I can send email via the terminal. How do I do that?

Answer (score 13):

Traditionally, Unix mail programs, including `mail`, rely on a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) to do the actual transmission.

You can use either a full-size MTA (postfix, exim4, opensmtpd) by configuring it with a 'smarthost' (relayhost), or a lightweight outgoing-only MTA (msmtp, ssmtp, esmtp, nullmailer) which *always* uses one.

---

For personal use, `msmtp` will be easiest to set up – it can only send mail, not receive, and allows user-specific configuration.

Install `msmtp`, then add your Gmail account into `~/.msmtprc`:

```
defaults
    tls on
    # the path below may need to be adjusted
    tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account gmail
    from youraddress@gmail.com
    host smtp.gmail.com
    port 587
    auth plain
    user youraddress@gmail.com

account default : gmail
```

Now tell `mail` to use `msmtp`, by editing `~/.mailrc`:

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
```

(If this does not work, run `ln -s /usr/bin/msmtp /usr/sbin/sendmail` as root.)

Finally, if you want `mail`/`msmtp` to remember your Gmail password, it goes to `~/.netrc`:

```
machine smtp.gmail.com
    login youraddress@gmail.com
    password "your password here"
```

Comment: `password "your password here"`  Tread carefully. I set this up with a gmail account dedicated to my machine, only to send notifications like from apt-listchanges.  I would _never ever *ever*_ do this with my personal gmail

Answer (score 3):

Unless your system admin has already set up the mail system, you must configure a Mail Transfer Agent. That is sendmail traditionally, modern systems use postfix or exim4.

- http://www.postfix.org/
- http://exim.org/

Answer (score 2):

On many systems you will find a `mailx` command which can be used to send email.  This may be a link to the mail command, but changes the behavior of the command.  As other have noted, this assumes you have a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) configured on your server.  It can be used interactively using a command like:

```
mailx -s "This is a message" user@example.com
This is a message
.
```

Or with a pipe to send the output of a command:

```
cat myfile.txt | mailx -s "This is the file" user@example.com
```

Running it as `mailx -h` should give you usage instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bound to the `mail` command, [`nail`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) offers a similar interface but can send mail using SMTP.